# Split texts by tags and set column names

Tags: r, regex, split

I have a text column that has a tag style. I want to split this text into columns where column names are the tags with their corresponding values.

```
text = "{\"article_id\":-41,\"word-count\":379,\"article_date\":05012017,\"source\":\"news::abc\",\"author\":\"Peter K\",\"title\":\"The rise of AI\",\"topics\":{\"Business\":10, \"Computer\":5},\"topics-group\":[{\"primary\":\"Business\",\"secondary\":\"Computer\"}]}"
```

Desired output:

```
data = data.frame("article_id" = -41, "word-count" = 379, "article_date" = 05012017,
                  "source"= "news::abc", "author" = "Peter K", "title" = "The rise of AI",
                  "topics" = "{\"Business\":10, \"Computer\":5}", 
                  "topics-group" = "[{\"primary\":\"Business\",\"secondary\":\"Computer\"}]")
```

I tried with `strsplit`

```
test = strsplit(as.character(text), ",\\\"")
test
[[1]]
[1] "{\"article_id\":-41"                        "word-count\":379"                          
[3] "article_date\":05012017"                    "source\":\"news::abc\""                    
[5] "author\":\"Peter K\""                       "title\":\"The rise of AI\""                
[7] "topics\":{\"Business\":10, \"Computer\":5}" "topics-group\":[{\"primary\":\"Business\"" 
[9] "secondary\":\"Computer\"}]}"
```

but there are problems with tags like `topics-group` which is split into 2.

My workflow thought is to complete the split, then do another split for each element to separate the tags and values. But I think there must be a better way to split and set names to these tags as column names.

Comment: This is a bit corrupt JSON, it makes sense to fix this on the provider's side. Is it the structure always the same?

Comment: Look into using the `rjson` library, but as @Wiktor has commented, the `05012017` value for the `article_date` is an octal, which JSON does not support.  Put that value in double quotes to make your JSON pass validation.

Comment: Now I see this is a JSON kind of file, I will look more into `rjson`.

Comment: Try `text <- gsub('("article_date":)(\\d+)', '\\1"\\2"', text)` and then use `library(jsonlite)` and `document <- fromJSON(txt=text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: there are some JSON dates in my data, e.g., `"article_date": 1172898060`. Is there a manual way to convert them to R date? I tried with `jsonlite::fromJSON` but the output is still a JSON date. I know it's better to address this from data provider's side but I only have the data as it is.

Comment: After you parse the JSON, you can re-format date fields "manually".

Comment: If you can explain what exact value you would like to see instead `05012017`, I could try to help more.

Answer (score 2):

We may do this in [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. Use [`str_replace_all`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_replace) to change the digits (`\\d+`) after the 'article_date":' to `integer` class (as there was a 0 padding at the beginning)
2. Use [`fromJSON`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RJSONIO/versions/1.3-1.4/topics/fromJSON) to convert the JSON to R object
3. Flatten the nested list of `data.frame` - `invoke`
4. Use `as_tibble` to convert the `list` to a `tibble`
5. Finally, use `mdy` from `lubridate` to convert the 'article_date' to `Date` class

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
text %>%
     str_replace_all('(?<=article_date":)(\\d+)',  as.integer) %>%
     fromJSON %>% 
     invoke(c, .) %>%
     as_tibble %>% 
     mutate(article_date = mdy(article_date))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 10
  article_id `word-count` article_date source   author  title       topics.Business topics.Computer `topics-group.prima… `topics-group.second…
       <int>        <int> <date>       <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                 <int>           <int> <chr>                <chr>                
1        -41          379 2017-05-01   news::a… Peter K The rise o…              10               5 Business             Computer
```

Answer (score 0):

You cam add double quotes around the `article_date` field and parse the JSON string with `jsonlite`:

```r
text <- gsub('("article_date":)(\\d+)', '\\1"\\2"', text)

library(jsonlite)
document <- fromJSON(txt=text)
> as.data.frame(document)
#   article_id word.count article_date    source  author          title topics.Business topics.Computer topics.group.primary topics.group.secondary
# 1        -41        379     05012017 news::abc Peter K The rise of AI              10               5             Business               Computer
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pFtVR7/1). *Details*:

- `("article_date":)` - Group 1: `"article_date":` string
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits.

The replacement is `\1"\2"`: Group 1 value + Group 2 value enclosed with double quotation marks.